# When I open a page from browser localhost it's different than when I'm opening it from htdocs folder

Tags: php, html, css

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa34J.png)

[Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wtU8.png)

The 'Error' pic is what I get when I go on localhost, browse through pages and end up there.
The 'Good' pic is what I want to achieve, that is what I get when I specifically open the page from the htdocs folder.

The change in the font is well made, saved, as you can see in the second picture. I just cannot seem to understand why it redirects me to the old page ( that's how it used to look).

This is how I made the redirect in the pages : `<a href="../../Doggo-success/dist/index.html"> TEXT </a>`

Comment: _"I just cannot seem to understand why it redirects me to the old page ( that's how it used to look)."_ - nothing "redirected" you anywhere. It sounds like you might simply have a problem with your browser cache serving you an old version ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any more details and code it's a bit hard to say. However, since you said that this is how the page used to look like here are some things I would check first:

- Delete browser-cache or hard-reload (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>)
- Is the correct HTML and JS-/CSS-files loaded and referenced? This can be easily done in the browser devtools (<kbd>F12</kbd> in most browsers).
- If you use a framework, the served files might get aggregated and cached. So maybe also delete your PHP Cache (e.g. `./bin/console cache:clear` for Symfony)

Your `<a>`-tag seems right, but without a clearer overview of your routing-system or folder-structure it is not possible to be 100% sure. Please make sure, that you call the right file here.

I hope that these steps already solve your problem. If not, I need a bit more information to be able to help.